# Switch statement more than one case executed - C programming

Tags: c, switch-statement

my code:
i'm a beginner - so go easy on me
so, switch statement in the following code executes statements of more than one case. i can't seem to find the problem. everything seems to be right.
check out the output image and my code, i need help.

```
//write a program that acts as a simple "printing" calculator
//enter expressions in the format "operator number"
//include operators to 'set accumulator' and 'end execution'
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 float number, accumulator;
 char operator;

 printf("Begin Calculations: (Enter 'S' operator to set the accumulator and 'E' operator to end execution)\n");
 printf("-------------------\n\n");

 while(operator != 'E')
 {
  scanf("%c%f", &operator, &number);
  switch(operator)
  {
   case 'S':
     accumulator = number;
     break;
   case '+':
     accumulator += number;
     break;
   case '-':
     accumulator -= number;
     break;
   case '*':
     accumulator *= number;
     break;
   case '/':
     accumulator /= number;
     break;
   case 'E':
     printf("End of Calculations.\n");
     break;
   default:
     printf("Enter proper Expression.\n");
     break;
  }
  printf("= %f\n", accumulator);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

[image: click for output:]

Comment: Don't post images of text! And **always** check the result of functions which can encounter an error relevant for your program.

Comment: your `scanf` is reading the ENTER into `operator` *(and failing to read a floating point number into `number`* **in a loop!!)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` returns an integer which indicates the number of variables that were succesfully assigned from your format specifier.

You're not checking the return value of `scanf` but then proceeding to use the variables to which you expected it to assign values. This is always a mistake.

`scanf` is probably failing, and your loop is continuing with the previous value of `operator`.

You should check that, in this case, `scanf` returns 2. Otherwise, it did not get valid input and your variables are unchanged.